# Convergence criteria for random field

Tags: hypothesis-testing, convergence, random-field

I am iteratively solving a stochastic equation by generating a random field and using the resulting generation to move toward an equilibrium. I know that the system converges but I want to use an appropriate stopping criteria.

At equilibrium, I know that if I continue to iterate, the mean change over many iterations will be 0 at every node $x$ in the field. My null hypothesis $H_0$ at equilibrium is that the change in value at each point $\Delta X_{i}$ will follow a normal distribution with mean 0 and unknown variance.

Let's say I have $N$ nodes. Therefore, if I keep track of the changes over the previous $T$ time steps, I can compute a student's t-distribution test statistic for each node

$K_i = \frac{\langle \Delta X_i \rangle_T}{\sigma_{i,T} /\sqrt{n}}$, for $i = 1,2,...,N$

where

$\langle \Delta X_i \rangle_T = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T\Delta x_{i,t}$

and

$\sigma_{i,T} = \frac{1}{T-1}\sum_{t=1}^{T}(\Delta x_{i,t}-\langle \Delta X_i \rangle_T)^2 $.

This is where I am a little uncertain. I can check each node individually for acceptance (say rejecting the null hypothesis with $\alpha = 0.05$ significance level). My plan to decide whether my whole system is at equilibrium is to treat each node as Bernoulli trial. I can compute $R$ such that $P(R_o<R) = 0.95$ (0.95, or any probability I want to prescribe), where $R_o$ is the observed number of rejections by inverting the cumulative binomial distribution resulting from probability $\alpha = 0.05$ and $N$ trials for my desired acceptance probability. Therefore I can say if my actual number of observed rejections $R_{o,actual} > R$, I am not yet at equilibrium.

Does this make sense? One area where I'm still confused is that, this scheme seems to be independent of the value of $\alpha$. Is that correct? Is there a different test that would be more appropriate?